# Image in use by seemingly non-existent container

Tags: container, podman

I've got Podman 3.4.4 running on Ubuntu 22.04 and see an obsolete image listed in `podman images`:

```
<none>        <none>    fa715d6fb372  6 days ago    585 MB
```

I ran

```bash
podman rmi fa715d6fb372
```

but was informed

```
Deleted: fa715d6f...
Deleted: 14600586...
Error: Image used by 6f4b5b90...: image in use by a container
```

However, `podman ps -a` shows no containers.

Furthermore, running

```bash
podman rm 6f4b5b90...
```

produces

```
Error: container "6f4b5b90..." is mounted and cannot be removed without using force: container state improper
```

Running

```bash
podman inspect 6f4b5b90...
```

displays

```
[]
Error: error inspecting object: no such object: "6f4b5b90..."
```

I can remove the offending container via `podman rm -f` and then delete the image.  However, why is this container not showing up under `podman ps -a`?

Comment: what do you want to know?

Comment: Why is it saying that the image is being used by a container while showing no results by `podman ps -a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a guess.

There's note in the documentation for `podman ps -a` [here](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-ps.1.html#all-a) that says:

> Note: Podman shares containers storage with other tools such as Buildah and CRI-O. In some cases these `external` containers might also exist in the same storage. Use the `--external` option to see these external containers. External containers show the ‘storage’ status.

I would start by following that instruction and checking for anything else with a container on your system.  Even if you think that's impossible, it's worth ruling out by checking.

Comment: This [GitHub comment](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/13497#issuecomment-1066572039) has a similar explanation and also mentions `podman rmi --force`

Comment: That did it!  It was something related to Docker.